# SharePoint Online - Calendar Overlay Colors are Mismatched

Tags: sharepoint-online, css, sharepoint-calendar, modern-team-site

I am trying to use the calendar overlays but I noticed the colors options do not match up with what is shown in the box or calendar.

Has anyone been experiencing this with SharePoint Modern sites (a team site) while trying to use the Calendar overlay?

There are no customizations on the site, no SPFX solutions, it is OOTB.

[image: Calendar Overlay mismatch between the color listed and the color rendered]

Answer (score 2):

I have reproduced your issue.

The colors are controlled by the css classes from ms-acal-color1 to ms-acal-color9 stored in Themable/corev15.css. And the color options are based on the site theme.

SharePoint online has modern experience and classic experience. And it has modern themes and classic themes.

In the modern experience, we click Settings [image] and then click Change the look > change the modern theme.

[image]

Click “Classic change the look options” to go to the “Change the look” page to change classic themes. Or, you can open Site settings -> Look and Feel  -> Change the look to open this page.

[image]

However, the calendar only has classic view. If we change the modern theme, it still uses style defined in corev15.css based on the classic theme. It causes the color mismatch issue.
[image]

**Solution:**

You need to navigate to “Change the look” page to use the classic theme back.

Site settings -> Look and Feel  -> Change the look -> Select a theme -> Try it out -> Yes, keep it.

If you don’t want to use the classic theme back, you can use scripts to change the colors. Refer to [this blog](https://davidlozzi.com/2012/06/20/customize-the-sharepoint-calendar-colors/) and [this demo](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/set-user-defined-colors-for-calendar-overlay/).

For this color issue when using modern theme, you can contact with Office 365 technical support from Support > New Service request to give a feedback.

[How to contact Office 365 support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/contact-support-for-business-products-admin-help-32a17ca7-6fa0-4870-8a8d-e25ba4ccfd4b#ID0EAADAAA=online)

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I thought it was something funky happening with the misalignment between the modern and classic color themes and since the Calendar overlay is still using the classic look and feel, it didnt pick up from the modern colors.

One alternative I thought of was to activate the publishing feature and using alternate css, override the colors. However, this site does not need the publishing feature, so I will reach out to MSFT support and hopefully there is a better solution.

Thank you!